# "Resource temporarily unavailable" when using Awk and Fork

Tags: bash, awk, cygwin

I wrote a script that it takes a csv file and replace the third column with the HASH of the second column with some string (Key). 
After 256 rows, I got an error

> awk: cmd. line:3: (FILENAME=C:/hanatest/test.csv FNR=257) fatal:
>   cannot create child process for `echo -n
>   E5360712819A7EF1584E2FDA06287379FF5CC3E0A5M7J6PiQMaSBut52ZQhVlS4 |
>   openssl ripemd160 | cut -f2 -d" "' (fork: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable)

I change the CSV file and I got always the same error after 256 rows.

here is my code:

```
awk -F "," -v env_var="$key" '{
    tmp="echo -n "$2env_var" | openssl ripemd160 | cut -f2 -d\" \""
tmp | getline cksum
$3=toupper(cksum)
print
}' //test/source.csv > //ziel.csv
```

Can you please help me ?

Here my sample input:

```
25,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,?
44,YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY,?
84,ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ,?
```

and here my expected output:

```
25,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,301E2A8BF32A7046F65E48DF32CF933F6CAEC529
44,YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY,301E2A8BF32A7046F65E48EF32CF933F6CAEC529
84,ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ,301E2A8BF32A7046F65E48EF33CF933F6CAEC529
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're running a new process for every input row, and I suspect not terminating it, so you're hitting a limit of 256 processes or pipes or something. What does `ulimit -a` say? [edit: actually, I'm confused what you're trying to do in that code, but I still think you're hitting a limit.]

Comment: thanks for your reply, here the output of ulimit -a:

$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2032
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

Comment: any idea to change the code to get my output ?

Comment: Since you haven't shown us any sample input or expected output - no. To patch your code, though, add `close(tmp)` after the line where you call getline but then read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline to see what else you're missing.

Comment: Something like the following should help you ... awk is complicating things: `export IFS=,$'\n'; while read a b c rest; do echo $a $b $(echo $b | openssl ripemd160 | cut -f2 -d' ') $rest; done` ... As @EdMorton suggests, you're hitting a pipe limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make your code more robust first:

```
awk -F "," -v env_var="$key" '{
    tmp="echo -n \047" $2 env_var "\047 | openssl ripemd160 | cut -f2 -d\047 \047"
    if ( (tmp | getline cksum) > 0 ) {
        $3 = toupper(cksum)
    }
    close(tmp)
    print
}' /test/source.csv > /ziel.csv
```

Now - do you still have a problem? If you're considering using getline make sure to read and fully understand the correct uses and all of the caveats discussed at http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: Thanks Ed, it works for sample data, but when I use it for a big csv (1Go) it is too slow i think. I run the script yesterday and  now i get only 30Mo. Actually the size of the original csv data is 1Go so i think it will finish after one month